# Apache2 Mysql and php7.0 function_exists('mysql_connect') returns false

Tags: mysql, apache2, php-7

I've installed the lamp stack on ubuntu 16.04 with `apt-get install lamp-server` and PHP is working but the `function_exists('mysql_connect')` returns `false`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_connect` is deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and was removed in PHP 7: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php